# Like a class constructor Is there a function constructor exist in python

Tags: python, python-requests

Recently I have come across a Python function as follows:

```
def pw_amp(k, x0):
    def _pw_amp(x):
        return cmath.exp(1j * k.dot(x + x0))
    return _pw_amp
```

Here the `_pw_amp` seems like a constructor for the function `pw_amp`. But I did not see any function constructor before. Is it like a class constructor? Please tell me how `_pw_amp` works.

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance of a decorator. Here's a good [article explaining them](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/), but the gist is that a decorator *modifies* an existing function. Eg,

```
@my_decorator
def my_function():
    ...
```

Is a fancy way of doing this.

```
def my_function():
    ...
my_function = my_decorator(my_function)
```